# How can I verify if SSH is disabled with the Terminal on Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

I would like to know the command line to verify the status of SSH on Sierra please.

I tried using systemctl but got a `command not found`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
```

This will return "Remote Login: On" or "Off" depending on the state of the Remote Login option in Sharing.prefpane.

There's no such thing as systemctl on macOS, but systemsetup does many things; check the list with `sudo systemsetup -help`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "systemctl" seems with I am conversing with another Linux person crossing over.  I feel your struggle. :)  I would use the same method to check this on both platforms.

Confirm if the port is open. Don't trust the vendor tools, they change, often.

Mac: `netstat -anl|grep LISTEN|grep "*.22"`

Linux: `netstat -anl|grep LISTEN|grep ":22"`

Comment: How do you know that the service listening on port 22 is indeed `sshd`?

Comment: @SAlder Tried this command and it returned nothing does that mean that port 22 is locked ?